# How do I dynamically update my Java Swing GUI for a board game from a separate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, java-threads

I am in the process of making a board game with a Java Swing GUI. The game is that of Bao which features an 8x4 playing board of "holes" where each "hole" contains a certain number of seeds. A player can complete two different types of moves these being a capture or non-capture. These moves involve picking up all the seeds from one of the "holes" and placing them one by one in adjacent holes and this is known as a sow.

My game rules are separated into a "Game class" containing the sow function which operates on a 8x4 array of integers.

```
private int[][] board = new int[4][8];
```

A portion of the sow function is as follows for placing one seed in an adjacent hole.

```
BaoGUI gui; // This a reference to the Java Swing GUI passed into the sow function 
board[row][column] += 1; 

if (gui != null) 
{
    Thread updateGuiThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            gui.updateBoard();               
        } 
        catch (Exception e)  
        {
            System.out.println("Update GUI thread interrupted.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished on " + Thread.currentThread());
    }
};
updateGuiThread.start();
Thread.sleep(500);
```

My Java Swing GUI class holds an object of type "Game" and calls games' sow() function based on user input. As seen above the sow() function places a seed in a hole then moves to the next hole and places another etc.

My updateBoard() function in the GUI class is as follows

```
public void updateBoard()
{
    int[][] board = game.getBoard();
    javax.swing.JButton but;
    String butName = "";

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++)
        {
            butName = "b" + i + j;
            but = (javax.swing.JButton)getComponentByName(butName);
            but.setText(Integer.toString(board[i][j]));
        }
    }
}
```

The effect I want to achieve is that for each placement of a seed the "board" in the GUI should update in an "animated" fashion. However with the above code the updating of the board occurs all at once i.e. only the final board state is displayed without the individual seed placement animation. After some rigorous testing of the above code I managed to ascertain that when I call the Games' sow() function from within the GUI class the sow() function executes on Swings' Event Dispatcher Thread. I thought perhaps that since all the game rule processing was happening on this thread that if I created a new thread for updating the GUI board that each individual seed placement would be seen but to no avail.

I also tried creating a Runnable thread for updating the GUI board as follows.

```
final Runnable externalUpdateBoard = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        int[][] board = game.getBoard();
        javax.swing.JButton but;
        String butName = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                butName = "b" + i + j;
                but = (javax.swing.JButton) getComponentByName(butName);
                but.setText(Integer.toString(board[i][j]));
            }
        }


        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception occured in externalUpdateBoard thread.");
        }
    }
};
```

I then ran this executable thread from within my Games' sow() function as follows

```
Thread updateGuiThread = new Thread() 
{
    public void run() {
       try {
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(gui.externalUpdateBoard);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Update GUI thread interrupted.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished on " + Thread.currentThread());
    }
};
updateGuiThread.start();
```

Once again the GUI did update but in the same "all at once" fashion without the animations.

How can I get the updateBoard() function im GUI to execute immediately each time a seed is placed in the sow() function?

Comment: Use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20javax.swing.Timer) to pace the animation.